# UTF8 Dingbats + Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dingbats

Is there a way to set the text of an element to something like ✘ (`&#10008;`) using JQuery?

ie:

```
$('#something').text('`&#10004;`'); //only ends in tears.
```

Comment: you can make a literal string expression using JSON.stringify(hardCodedChar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode` is the tool you need.

```
$('#something').text(String.fromCharCode(10004)); //Checkmark
```

Comment: Wow. Sad part is I tried that, however, I left the &#... Sigh.
Thank you :)